How to exclude Version from SHA calculation in .NET
I build a .NET solution through Github Actions like so:
dotnet build --configuration Release --no-restore --verbosity normal /p:Version=${VERSION}

VERSION is set to the current repo tag. With each release, I can dynamically set the version.
The problem is this seems to be causing assemblies that have not changed to produce a different SHA. For example, when I run shasum on a DLL, I see a different SHA even if there are no change changes.
Is there a way to make sure the version does not get included in SHA calculation?
I do not set AssemblyVersion, FileVersion, or BuildVersion anywhere in the code (i.e. nothing in csproj, props, or cs files).

Do you miss  <Deterministic>true</Deterministic> compiler key? In your global or sub-directory Directory.Build.MSBuild.props...
But ...Version are assembly attributes. They are stored physically in an assembly executable file, more exactly, in the metadata of the manifest of the main assembly module (usually the only one) with the assembly manifest. This piece of metadata is important and can be used. If you don't want it, you should not use versions in your build.

So, if by shasum you mean a separate universal utility used to calculate SHA out of an arbitrary file, it should produce different results for the different versions (even without any other difference) of your DLL, if it is a .NET assembly module with an assembly manifest.

shasum is a perl script that calculates the SHA checksum value of a file. The SHA algorithm doesn't know or care about .Net assembly versions. If the files are different, the SHA checksum will be different.

Where and how are you running Github Actions (or your automated build tool of choice)? Are you performing a full build every time? (i.e. are you clearing prior build files and/or acquiring a new build agent for each build?) MSBuild incremental builds only work against prior build files. If there isn't a prior DLL file, MSBuild can't determine that the source files are older than the DLL and that the DLL doesn't need to be built.

I run a full build each time and explicitly remove the artifacts folder so MSBuild writes to a brand new folder. I use Github-hosted runners, so I assume each runner is a new VM/container. I have set Deterministic already. I tested the version locally. If I exclude it, .NET will produce the same exact SHA for each DLL (in a new artifacts folder) no matter how often the build runs.

Yes, with a full build when you supply a different value for $(Version) you are producing a different DLL - even when no source code has changed. Two possible approaches - 1.) Preserve the artifacts folder and re-use the exact same agent so that incremental builds can occur. The DLL with no source code changes will not build and will not use the "new" version. This is probably impractical for lots of reasons. 2.) Separate your current solution into individual builds for each DLL and change the build triggers so that you only build a DLL when there are source code changes for that DLL.
